# Opening new view from Navigation Drawer in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, navigation-drawer

I made a new Xamarin Android project in Visual Studio and I chose a Navigation Drawer App, which created this solution:

https://github.com/dkaczor97/XamarinNavigationDrawer.git

Now my problem is, that I can't find how to open new view when item from the drawer is selected. I tried opening new Activity but then the drawer disapears until I go back to main view. Could anyone guide me how to add new views in this kind of app? Should I add the navigation bar and drawer to every single view?
I will be grateful for every tip

Comment: Have a look:: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/android5.0/NavigationDrawer/

Comment: Now I see that I should use Fragment instead of Activity, but I don't get what should I replace with my new Fragment. The xml layout files are completely different. In the example it replaces FrameLayout.

Comment: Yes you can also follow the same in your application.